# Parameter not valid exception when saving image from picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing, save

I am trying to save an image from a picturebox1 element in a windows form, but the `Image.Save` method throws a parameter not valid exception and I can't work out why.

```
 string name = "BookCover_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpeg";
            string path = pathFolder + name;

            if (Directory.Exists(pathFolder))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
```

This is the error message that I am getting:

```
    System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at LibraryProject.Forms.CameraForm.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\git\libraryproject\LibraryProject.Core\LibraryProject.Forms\CameraForm.cs:line 172
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at LibraryProject.Forms.Program.Main() in C:\git\libraryproject\LibraryProject.Core\LibraryProject.Forms\Program.cs:line 19
```

Comment: Are you sure that pictureBox1.Image is a valid image? This error code happens usually when bad image data is used.

Comment: How did the Image get inside the PictureBox Control? Where does it come from? What is the original format? What is `pathFolder + name`?

Comment: the picturebox holds a frame from a live feed of the computer's webcam, in a videosourceplayer (using the Aforge libraries). I think it's a bitmap image, but I want to save it as a jpeg. `pathfolder` is the path of the folder that I'm saving the image in, and `name` is the name of the file, together they are supposed to be the `string filename` parameter of image.save

Comment: `string path = pathFolder + "\\"+ name;` ?

Comment: I have included the `"\\"` which precedes `name` in the pathfolder variable, so I don't think this is where the error is coming from. I also tried using the pathfolder string directly into the declaration of path, rather than in a variable but this didn't solve it either.